# Ruby - mathematica style tuples lists

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, tuples

I'm playing around with large lists of multiple combinations of vars, I'm curious if ruby implements a way to generate these lists given a length and list of variables, the same way mathematica deals with tuples.

Given the length 3 and variables a, b and c it would output an array or arrays with every combination of a, b, c, 3 long

abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba

Usually this would just be easy to do, except im working with lists 10-15 in length with 10 or so vars

Comment: Could you please clarify (with an edit, not a comment) what you mean by "with lists 10-15 in length with 10 or so vars."?  In your example, if the length were 4, rather than 3, with the same 3 variables, would one of the permutations be, say, 'abac'?  Note that Ruby's `permutations` and `combinations` generate the entire arrays in memory. If that's a problem, there are ways to step through the permutations one at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`permutations`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) method for arrays:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
p letters.permutation(3).map(&:join)
#=> ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```